# Passing vars to Molecule with Github Runner

Tags: ansible, github-actions

I am trying to test a github workflow that among other things installs one of several versions of a program.  The version numbers are part of a matrix within the workflow file but I can't figure out how to actually get them into molecule so that the playbook sees the variable and can do something with it.  Pay attention to the `version` variable

```
workflow.yml
jobs:
  molecule:
    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        molecule_distro:
          - container: mysql-centos
            image: geerlingguy/docker-rockylinux8-ansible:latest
            group: mysql
        collection_role:
          - server_role
        version:
          - 6.2
          - 6.0
          - 5.0
    steps:
      - name: Check out code
        uses: actions/checkout@v1

      - name: Set up Python 3.7
        uses: actions/setup-python@v1
        with:
          python-version: 3.7

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          pip install -r molecule/requirements.txt

      - name: Build the collection
        run: |
          collection_file=$( basename $(ansible-galaxy collection build -f | awk -F" " '{print $NF}'))
          echo "COLLECTION_FILE=$collection_file" >> $GITHUB_ENV

      - name: Install the collection
        run: ansible-galaxy collection install $COLLECTION_FILE

      - name: Run role tests
        run: >-
          MY_MOLECULE_CONTAINER=${{ matrix.molecule_distro.container }}
          MY_MOLECULE_IMAGE=${{ matrix.molecule_distro.image }}
          MY_MOLECULE_GROUP=${{ matrix.molecule_distro.group }}
          MY_MOLECULE_DOCKER_COMMAND=${{ matrix.molecule_distro.command }}
          MY_MOLECULE_VERSION=${{ matrix.version }}
          molecule test -s ${{ matrix.collection_role }}
```

molecule.yml

```
driver:
  name: docker
platforms:
  - name: zabbix-server-${MY_MOLECULE_CONTAINER:-mysql-centos}
    image: ${MY_MOLECULE_IMAGE:-"geerlingguy/docker-centos8-ansible"}
    command: ${MY_MOLECULE_DOCKER_COMMAND:-""}
    privileged: true
    pre_build_image: true
    networks:
      - name: zabbix
    volumes:
      - /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro
    groups:
      - ${MY_MOLECULE_GROUP:-mysql}

provisioner:
  name: ansible
  lint:
    name: ansible-lint
  env:
    ANSIBLE_COLLECTIONS_PATHS: $HOME/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/community/my_collection
    ANSIBLE_ROLES_PATH: $HOME/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/community/my_collection/roles
    THE_VERSION: ${MY_MOLECULE_VERSION:-"6.2"}
```

converge.yml

```
---
- hosts: all
  become: true
  roles:
    - role: server_role
      server_version: "{{ lookup('ansible.builtin.env', 'THE_VERSION') }}"
```

When it runs on the 6.2 version it works fine

```
TASK [server_role : RedHat | Install basic repo file] ************************
changed: [server] => (item={'name': 'repo', 'description': 'Server Official Repository - $basearch', 'baseurl': 'https://repo.server.com/server/6.2/rhel/8/$basearch/', 'gpgcheck': 0, 'mode': '0644', 'gpgkey': 'file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-SERVER', 'state': 'present'})
```

But not so much with others (notice the missing version number between `server` and `rhel` in the baseurl.

```
TASK [server_role : RedHat | Install basic repo file] ************************
changed: [server] => (item={'name': 'repo', 'description': 'Server Official Repository - $basearch', 'baseurl': 'https://repo.server.com/server//rhel/8/$basearch/', 'gpgcheck': 0, 'mode': '0644', 'gpgkey': 'file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-SERVER', 'state': 'present'})
```

Comment: Does it change anything if you add `export` in the declaration of the `MY_*` variables in the workflow?

Comment: And when putting the env variables in the `env` section of the step (https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsenv)?